# ActiveRecord rails 4 not equal to condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I am using rails 4 for developing my application. I have a problem in my active record query with not equal to condition. I am not getting required output. I think there is a problem with not equal to part.

```
@available_rooms = Room.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN reservations ON reservations.room_id = rooms.id").where("category_id = ? AND arrival_date != ?",params[:category],params[:arrival_date])
```

Comment: `<>` worked for you?

Comment: @Cyzanfar yes it did :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In some version of SQL not equal is written as `!=`

Try this using the comparator  `<>` like so:

```
 @available_rooms = Room.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN reservations ON reservations.room_id = rooms.id")
.where("category_id = ? AND arrival_date <> ?",params[:category],params[:arrival_date])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `where.not()` in Rails 4 :

```
 @available_rooms = Room.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN reservations ON reservations.room_id = rooms.id")
                        .where(category_id: params[:category])
                        .where.not(arrival_date: params[:arrival_date])
```